# Como Contar total de multiplos tipo registros em uma Unica consulta no sql

Tags: php, mysql

Ola Hoje eu estou fazendo as contagens de registro desta forma

```
$sql1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total1 FROM a_finan Where  cat = 'Ativos' ;
$resultado1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die ("Erro na consulta1");
$linha1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado1);
echo $total1 = $linha1['total1'];

$sql2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total2 FROM a_finan Where  cat = 'Inativos' ;
$resultado2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die ("Erro na consulta2");
$linha2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado2);
echo  $total2 = $linha2['total2'];
```

a 1º Conta total de registro ativos
a 2º conta total de registros inativos 
e 3º segue na mesma...

Teria alguma forma de fazer uma contagem em unica consulta para o código não ficar gigante

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT cat, COUNT(*) as total
FROM a_finan
GROUP BY cat
```

Isso vai trazer o total de registros agrupado por categoria '`cat`'.

Comment: Ok acho que é isso mesmo Poderia só me explica como mostrar os registros separados por cat?

Comment: Você vai conseguir a resposta da mesma forma que antes... A diferença agora, é que vai retornar mais de uma linha então vc vai ter que percorrer o array. Algo tipo isso:

$resultado = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Erro na consulta");
$linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($linha)) {
    echo $row["total"] . '<br>';
}

Comment: Ola Ok Era isso mesmo. voce saberia me informar como passar cada resultado para uma variavel

Comment: Não sei exatamente o que vc precisa, mas se dentro do while() vc usar `$resultado[] = $row["total"]`. No final da execução, vc vai ter os valores dentro desse array. Aí é só usar $resultado[0], $resultado[1], $resultado[2]....

Comment: Acho que não funciona para oque eu estava querendo. cada resultado pertence a uma categoria = cat ele me retorna tipo 10 , 22, 15 como eu vou saber a quem pertence esse valores

Comment: Sim, funciona... essa query vai te retornar um array:[0] 'cat' => 'Ativo', 'total' => 10 | [1] 'cat' => 'Inativo', 'total' => 22 | [2] 'cat' => 'bla bla bla'. 'total' => 15.... Você terá exatamente cada categoria e o total agrupado... * Sei que a pergunta é antiga, mas pode ser útil a outra pessoas que chegarem até aqui com a mesma dúvida.